# MySQL getting the closest row available based on date

Tags: mysql

I'm measuring different kind of events daily and get records looking like that:

```
id    measurement_date            value
111   2020-12-01 21:30:00         100
111   2020-12-02 22:00:12         110
111   2020-12-03 21:35:17         80
114   2020-12-02 21:47:56         780
114   2020-12-04 21:55:47         700
....
```

Then I am having a query transforming the data to get the difference between 2 measurements.
I am running this transform on different windows of time (1 day, 7 days, 1 month).

For 1 day it is quite straightforward as I either have a measurement or if missing I have no intermediary data to compensate and therefore place a 0.

Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT id, 
    (ft.value - ft2.value) as progression,
FROM feed_table ft 
JOIN feed_table ft2 on ft2.id = ft.id 
AND date_format(ft2.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE date_format(ft.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

However for longer windows, like 7 days, for example, I would like to make use of the intermediary data if they exist.

Let's say I am measuring on the 7 days window between today 2020-12-08 and 7 days before 2020-12-01, but I only have the following measurements which are neither today nor 7 days ago but are still inside the 7 days window:

```
id    measurement_date            value
111   2020-12-02 21:30:00         200
111   2020-12-06 21:30:00         300
```

Then the query above with a 7D interval and the right settings should return :

```
id    progression
111   100
```

(max date value - min date value in the 7 days window)

I was thinking of aggregating by user_id and using the min-max date in the having close, but my self-join wouldn't work anymore...

Any idea?

Comment: Just to observe, by convention 'id' implies a surrogate primary key.

Comment: I understand, but for the sake of simplicity there are no constraints on this table

Comment: I don't get it... How do you go from `200` and `300` to `111 + 100`? That doesn't seem to be related at all.

Comment: let me reformat then.

Comment: (id,measurement_date) sure looks like a unique constraint (and I'd hope that it was)

Comment: (And what does date_format do?)

Comment: yes it is, only one insert per id per day indeed. The column measurement date can have the time for some events so I'm making sure I use the date only to calculate my interval.

Comment: That's not what your question implies, but anyway Date() is the normal function for that.

Comment: Also, I'm confused because there seem to be 5 dates within the window, not 2 !?!?